# how to formulate the objective function

Tags: optimization

Formulate and solve algebraically, through optimal conditions
first order, the problem of finding the point of the curve $x_{2} = x_{1}(3 − x_{1})$ that is closest to the point $(3 3)^{T}$. What is the guarantee that the point obtained is in fact the desired solution? Explain. Suggestion: explore the geometric visualization of the elements of the problem to assist you in algebraic analysis.

First part of the solution:
 The proposed problem is equivalent to
minimize $(x_{1} − 3)^{2} + (x_{2} − 3)^{2}$
subject to $x^{2}_{1} − 3x^{1} + x_{2} = 0$.
 My question is, how the author got there $f(x) =(x_{1} − 3)^{2} + (x_{2} − 3)^{2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the distance formula. When $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is minimised (write it out in terms of $x_1,x_2$), $f(x)$ is minimised as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, this problem has a global solution, can you tell me how the author saw this solution right away?

Comment: Through practice. If you are familiar with coordinate geometry, you will see this right away.

Comment: I sketched the circumference and the constraint function (which is a parabola), and saw that the circumference touches a point in the parabola. Would this point be a global solution?

Comment: Yes, this would be a global solution.

Comment: Thank you very much.